# Which animated file types are supported by iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I just want to add an animated file to my application.

Most of the postings I have read, are using UIImageViews or collection of the multiple images. I don't want to do that.

I just want to know which animated file formats are working on iOS (I know `.gif` and `.swf` are not working on iOS).

So is there any other file format, which I can use in my app OR let me know if there is any other framework to use the animated file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use gif. You need to show inside `UIWebView`.

Comment: @Helmi- is there any other option, without using webview + .gif

Answer (score 2):

we cant use any animated file like .gif, .swf because apple not allows us. if you want to animate the images just do that way.

```
  UIImageView* campFireView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

   // load all the frames of our animation
   campFireView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:   
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire01.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire02.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire03.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire04.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire05.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire06.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire07.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire08.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire09.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire10.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire11.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire12.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire13.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire14.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire15.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire16.png"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed:@"campFire17.png"], nil];

 // all frames will execute in 1.75 seconds
 campFireView.animationDuration = 1.75;
 // repeat the annimation forever
 campFireView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
 // start animating
 [campFireView startAnimating];
 // add the animation view to the main window
 [self.view addSubview:campFireView];
```

or  see that link  www.appsamuck.com/day2.html

Answer (score 1):

By default a GIF won't animate correctly in a UIImageView. However, with a little extra effort you can get them to work.

This project looks the most promising as it appears to actually decode the gif and display the individuals frames for you.

https://github.com/arturogutierrez/Animated-GIF-iPhone/

Otherwise, the other solutions I've seen are what you mentioned. (Separating the gif into multiple images manually)

http://www.alterplay.com/ios-dev-tips/2010/12/making-gif-animating-on-ios.html

Comment: i have download the code from github, it is fine, .gif is working with UIImage, but i have native application so i just try to load .gif image in UIWebview with NSdata but didn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use cocos2D for this animation. Use with CCSpriteSheet.